# How to capture backslashes with regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have the following along the lines of a CSS stylesheet: `content: "\f215";`.
I need to extract `f215` from it and I tried the following:

```
re.compile("content: \"\\([a-z0-9]+)\";")
```

I've tested this here http://www.pythonregex.com/ and it works like a charm.
However, when I paste this into a script and run it locally, it raises `sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis` and I'm at loss why.
I also tried

```
re.compile(re.escape('content: "\([a-z0-9]+)";')
re.compile('content: "\\\([a-z0-9]+)";')
```

but both don't match anything.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define your pattern as raw string.

```
re.compile(r'content: "\\([a-z0-9]+)";')
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dG9lM6/1)

```
>>> s = r'content: "\f215";'
>>> m = re.compile(r'content: "\\([a-z0-9]+)";')
>>> m.search(s).group(1)
'f215'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [*Lookaround*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to get the desired result

```
(?<=content: "\\)[a-z0-9]+(?=";)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dT7cF3/2)

Sample code:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<=content: "\\)[a-z0-9]+(?=";)')
test_str = u"content: \"\f215\";"

re.search(p, test_str)
```